# Можно ли автоматически генерировать у себя на сайте виджет "Запись на стене" для любой записи ВКонтакте?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мне нужно получать некоторое количество записей ВК именно (!) через виджет "Запись на стене", но проблема в том, что для каждой записи (или для каждого пользователя) нужно генерировать обязательный hash, без которого (или с неправильным) вместо записи можно получить ошибку доступа.

Скажите, можно ли как-нибудь динамически, без заходов на страницу в разделе для разработчиков, на которой и генерируется виджет вместе с хешем, самому генерировать хеш и получать любую запись?

Comment: надо создать свое приложение vk. получите ключ. и после этого сможете получать данные через vk api.

Comment: Нет, сгенерировать хеш не получится, так как неизвестно каким образом. Только парсить его скриптом.

Comment: @ModaL а у вас нет на примете готового скрипта?

Comment: @DeFF, неа. Но могу написать. Опишите конкретно что нужно получать. Смогу только на PHP.

Comment: @ModaL именно хеш для каждой записи. Я сам пытался-пытался, но у меня как-то не выходит даже войти в ВК через php, чтобы получить хеш.

Comment: @DeFF, хорошо, ждите.

Comment: придерживайтесь, пожалуйста, [принятой практики по поводу приветствий](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/93).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По просьбе написал скрипт, который получает hash записи. Переменная `$post_hash` возвращает хеш записи.

Подстройте под себя, если требуется, так как я уже не стал всё объединять в `class`.

```
<?php
/*
(!) Не предусмотрен ввод каптчи

Author: Ruslan Sadykhov (ModaL)
*/

$login = '7XXXXXXXX77';
$password = 'password';
$security_check_code = 'XXXXXXXX'; // если требуется 8 цифр номера телефона (по крайней мере у меня столько запросило)

$headers = array(
 'accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
 'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 'user-agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36'
);

// получаем главную страницу
$get_main_page = post('https://vk.com', array(
 'headers' => array(
  'accept: '.$headers['accept'],
  'content-type: '.$headers['content-type'],
  'user-agent: '.$headers['user-agent']
 )
));

// парсим с главной страницы параметры ip_h и lg_h
preg_match('/name=\"ip_h\" value=\"(.*?)\"/s', $get_main_page['content'], $ip_h);
preg_match('/name=\"lg_h\" value=\"(.*?)\"/s', $get_main_page['content'], $lg_h);

// посылаем запрос на авторизацию
$post_auth = post('https://login.vk.com/?act=login', array(
 'params' => 'act=login&role=al_frame&_origin='.urlencode('http://vk.com').'&ip_h='.$ip_h[1].'&lg_h='.$lg_h[1].'&email='.urlencode($login).'&pass='.urlencode($password),
 'headers' => array(
  'accept: '.$headers['accept'],
  'content-type: '.$headers['content-type'],
  'user-agent: '.$headers['user-agent']
 ),
 'cookies' => $get_main_page['cookies']
));

// получаем ссылку для редиректа после авторизации
preg_match('/Location\: (.*)/s', $post_auth['headers'], $post_auth_location);

if(!preg_match('/\_\_q\_hash=/s', $post_auth_location[1])) {
 echo 'Не удалось авторизоваться <br /> <br />'.$post_auth['headers'];

 exit;
}

// переходим по полученной для редиректа ссылке
$get_auth_location = post($post_auth_location[1], array(
 'headers' => array(
  'accept: '.$headers['accept'],
  'content-type: '.$headers['content-type'],
  'user-agent: '.$headers['user-agent']
 ),
 'cookies' => $post_auth['cookies']
));

// получаем ссылку на свою страницу
preg_match('/"uid"\:"([0-9]+)"/s', $get_auth_location['content'], $my_page_id);

$my_page_id = $my_page_id[1];

$get_my_page = getUserPage($my_page_id, $get_auth_location['cookies']);

// если запрошена проверка безопасности
if(preg_match('/act=security\_check/s', $get_my_page['headers'])) {
 preg_match('/Location\: (.*)/s', $get_my_page['headers'], $security_check_location);

 // переходим на страницу проверки безопасности
 $get_security_check_page = post('https://vk.com'.$security_check_location[1], array(
  'headers' => array(
   'accept: '.$headers['accept'],
   'content-type: '.$headers['content-type'],
   'user-agent: '.$headers['user-agent']
  ),
  'cookies' => $get_auth_location['cookies']
 ));

 // получаем hash для запроса на проверку мобильного телефона
 preg_match('/hash: \'(.*?)\'/s', $get_security_check_page['content'], $get_security_check_page_hash);

 // вводим запрошенные цифры мобильного телефона
 $post_security_check_code = post('https://vk.com/login.php', array(
  'params' => 'act=security_check&code='.$security_check_code.'&al_page=2&hash='.$get_security_check_page_hash[1],
  'headers' => array(
   'accept: '.$headers['accept'],
   'content-type: '.$headers['content-type'],
   'user-agent: '.$headers['user-agent']
  ),
  'cookies' => $get_auth_location['cookies']
 ));

 echo 'Запрошена проверка безопасности. Необходимо изменить значение в переменной $security_check_code и обновить страницу.';
} else {
 $post_hash = vkGetPostHash('https://vk.com/wall1_45616', $get_auth_location['cookies']);

 echo $post_hash;
}

function getUserPage($id = null, $cookies = null) {
 global $headers;

 $get = post('https://vk.com/id'.$id, array(
  'headers' => array(
   'accept: '.$headers['accept'],
   'content-type: '.$headers['content-type'],
   'user-agent: '.$headers['user-agent']
  ),
  'cookies' => $cookies
 ));

 return $get;
}

function vkGetPostHash($url = null, $cookies = null) {
 global $headers;

 preg_match('/(wall)(\-?[0-9]+)\_([0-9]+)/', $url, $matches);

 $get = post('https://vk.com/dev.php', array(
  'params' => 'act=a_get_post_hash&al=1&post='.$matches[2].'_'.$matches[3],
  'headers' => array(
   'accept: '.$headers['accept'],
   'content-type: '.$headers['content-type'],
   'user-agent: '.$headers['user-agent']
  ),
  'cookies' => $cookies
 ));

 preg_match('/\<(.*)\>(.*)/is', $get['content'], $hash_matches);

 $hash = $hash_matches[2];

 return $hash;
}

function post($url = null, $params = null) {
 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);

 if(isset($params['params'])) {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params['params']);
 }

 if(isset($params['headers'])) {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $params['headers']);
 }

 if(isset($params['cookies'])) {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $params['cookies']);
 }

 $result = curl_exec($ch);

 list($headers, $result) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 4);

 preg_match_all('|Set-Cookie: (.*);|U', $headers, $parse_cookies);

 $cookies = implode(';', $parse_cookies[1]);

 curl_close($ch);

 return array('headers' => $headers, 'cookies' => $cookies, 'content' => $result);
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь, это поможет не только мне, но и многим другим. Но при изменении ID поста оно выдаёт ошибку 

`Не удалось авторизоваться 

HTTP/1.1 302 Found Server: Apache Date: Tue, 29 Dec 2015 20:46:09 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251 Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By: PHP/3.20062 Set-Cookie: remixlang=0; expires=Sat, 31 Dec 2016 15:59:02 GMT; path=/; domain=.vk.com Pragma: no-cache Cache-control: no-store P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT" Location: http://vk.com/login.php?act=slogin&to=&s=0&m=4&email=`

Comment: Но, если обновить страницу, ошибка пропадает и можно получить хеш.

Comment: @DeFF, а где изменяете? Походу, что не там, так как эта ошибка говорит о том, что неправильный логин и пароль. Прикрепите код на pastebin.com, стерев свой логин с паролем.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/abjtXn32 - я сделал получение ID пользователя и его поста через GET-запрос и всё. Но пароль правильный, т.к. если ещё раз попробовать получить хеш (обновить страницу), то всё срабатывает.

Comment: @DeFF, страница с примером есть, чтобы протестировать?

Comment: http://37.235.240.53/ajaxi/postw.php?uid=-100793901&pid=455

Comment: @DeFF, мне кажется это какая-то проблема с Вашим сервером, не? Он еле грузит у меня страницу. Может ВКонтакте блокирует ip-адрес? Так как вот живой пример и всё работает без ошибок: http://isoption.vkmsg.ru/test.php?uid=-100793901&pid=455

Comment: действительно, у вас работает. Это странно. Хорошо, я что-нибудь придумаю с сервером. Ещё раз огромнейшее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @ModaL уже не работает этот способ видимо, есть дургие варианты?